# Unit test - Mockito and Butterknife - How to mock

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, mockito, butterknife

I have a method that I want to unit test, that calls `Butterknife(Object.class, Activity.class)` inside. It looks like this:

```
public void bindActivity(Activity activity) {
    this.activity = activity;
    unbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this, activity);
    init();
}
```

Test method:

```
@Test
public void testBindActivity() throws Exception {
    Activity activity = mock(Activity.class);

    tested.bindActivity(activity);

    assertNotNull(tested.activity);
    assertNotNull(tested.unbinder);
    verify(tested).init();
}
```

Test throws NPE in `Butterknife` class which make sense. I've tried using `Mockito.when()` in order to mock and "hide" that direct call to `Butterknife.bind()` and just retrun mocked `Unbinder` but without any success. Is there any solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

This may not answer your question but unit test is supposed to test the logic that YOU have written, not the logic built into your platform and libraries. Your first assert is testing java assignment operator. Your second assert is testing ButterKnife.bind method, and the last one is testing java method invocation mechanism!

Answer (score 0):

Yea, within your test class you need an instance variable like:

```
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class SomeTest {

    @Mock
    Activity mockActivity;

    ...

}
```

Then you need to inject it into the class you're testing like:

```
tested.bindActivity(mockActivity);
```

You're also probably wanna add some .when() stuff like:

```
when(mockActivity.callsSomeMethod()).thenReturn("something");
```

Hope that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot mock static method call like Butterknife.bind() with Mockito.

You could use Powermock to do this but for this kind of test you should make instrumented tests.

Take a look [here](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/index.html).